# execute a code after every 1/24 sec not working

Tags: javascript

I am trying to run a piece of code in requestFrameAnimation. The code should run after every 1/24 sec. I am using javascript date() library to get current time. Here is my code

```
animate = () => {

    let canvas = document.getElementById('timeline-canvas')
    let ctx =  canvas.getContext('2d')



    let currentTime = new Date().getTime() / 1000;


    if (currentTime >= lastTime + (1000/24))  {
        console.log(lastTime)
        // 1/24 second has passed, run some code here
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        ctx.beginPath()
        ctx.strokeStyle = 'blue'
        ctx.lineWidth = 5
        ctx.moveTo(x_pos, 0)
        ctx.lineTo(x_pos, canvas.height)
        ctx.stroke()
        ctx.save()
    }
    x_pos += 1
    lastTime = currentTime
    requestAnimationFrame(this.animate);

}
```

The if loop only runs once. I expect it to run every 1/24 sec. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what context is animate in? also you should debounce your timing instead of no blocking infinite loop else the dom lookup is going to hammer

Comment: @MikeCheel I'm assuming it's the `requestAnimationFrame`. But I'm prety sure `this.animate` isn't defined.

Comment: This should work fine. Can you create a small demo for this, so that we can use it to debug.

Comment: @Aplet123 yea I realized that right after I commented lol

Comment: requestAnimationFrame is working fine. The "if" loop inside animate is not getting executed every 1/24 sec

Comment: You should provide a [mcve] using the live demo feature of the question editor. (Note "minimal", unless it proves to be the cause of the problem you can ditch all the canvas stuff and replace it with logging).

Comment: thats because `lastTime = currentTime` is outside the if..

Comment: @LawrenceCherone It is supposed to be outside only. Then only lastTime will be updated even if the loop condition is false

Comment: @EdG There is no if "loop". You call your animate() function. Everything runs, the if works but at requestAnimationFrame(this.animate) will not work because this.animate is not defined. try requestAnimationFrame(animate). Maybe this works

Comment: requestAnimationFrame(this.animate) is correct. As I said, requestAnimationFrame is working perfectly. I think there I am making some mistake in lastTime and currentTime comparing.

Answer (score 0):

Your this part should be inside if statement

```
lastTime = currentTime
```

So it will look something like this

```
if (currentTime >= lastTime + (1000/24))  {
    console.log(lastTime)
    // 1/24 second has passed, run some code here
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    ctx.beginPath()
    ctx.strokeStyle = 'blue'
    ctx.lineWidth = 5
    ctx.moveTo(x_pos, 0)
    ctx.lineTo(x_pos, canvas.height)
    ctx.stroke()
    ctx.save()
    lastTime = currentTime
}
```

If you will place this statement out of the if block your last time will be updated every second. Mark as solved if it helped

Comment: Last time should be updated every second. By the way I tried your solution. It didn't work.  Thanks though for trying to help